# Compile Error: "Not a statement" - Equation inside a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors

I'm getting "Not a statement" when I attempt to do this:

```
quarter = roundedAmount / 25.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < quarter; i++) {
      roundedAmount - 25.0; //This line is the error in every loop.
    }
```

The task is to make a program which reads a number from the user between 1 and 99, rounds the number to the nearest five, and then outputs a string dependent on how many quarters/dimes/nickels will add up to the rounded value. I'm aware that I probably can't shove an equation like that into a for loop, but I can not, for the life of me, think of an alternate way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Maybe if I supply the rest of my class, you guys can spot any logic errors or whatnot.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
/*
 * Recieves an int < 100 and > -1 from the user (to act as "money") and returns the appropriate "change" to the user -
 * rounded to the nearest 5 and in the least amount of "coins" possible.
 * <br><br>
 * <b>Name: Riley Matchett<br>
 * ID: 991367312<br>
 * Date: 01/19/2015</b>
 */
public class MakeChange {
  /*
   * 
   * @param userAmount The user's input.
   * @return The change required.
   */
  public String calculate(int userAmount) {
    double roundedAmount;
    int quarter, dime, nickel;

    roundedAmount = Math.round(userAmount/5)*5;
    if (roundedAmount < userAmount) {
      return "No change needed."; 
    }

    quarter = roundedAmount / 25.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < quarter; i++) {
      roundedAmount - 25.0; //Error
    }

    dime = roundedAmount / 10.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dime; i++) {
      roundedAmount - 10.0; //Error
    }

    nickel = roundedAmount / 5.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nickel; i++) {
     roundedAmount - 5.0; //Error
    }

    String coins = userAmount + " cents requires: " + roundedAmount;
    return coins;
  }
  /*
   * 
   * @param args Unused
   * @throws IlegalArgumentException If userValue is less than 0, or greater than 99.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer from 0 - 99.");
    try {
      int userAmount = s.nextInt();
      if (userAmount < 0 || userAmount > 99) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Integer must be greater than 0, and less than 99."); 
      }
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
      System.err.println("Invalid input.");
    }
  }
}
```

I know there are unfinished segments, all I'm concerned with right now is the calculations, I'll deal with the String array once I'm through here.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need to assign the value to something. `roundedAmount - 25.0` is not enough.

Comment: What do you think `roundedAmount - 25.0;` should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: Fundamental misunderstanding of Java syntax. The - symbol does not do what you think it does. You need to read up on variable assignment.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a statement because it doesn't do anything. A statement in java must call a method or assign a value to a variable.

Did you want to say `roundedAmount -= 25.0;`? That would assign the result of subtracting 25 back to the roundedAmount variable.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that before posting, but I got the same error.

Comment: If you fix all your compile errors you will no longer have compile errors :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to decrease `roundedAmount` by `25`, use the following idiom:

```
roundedAmount -= 25.0;
```

The "non-statement" in your code is equivalent to the **value** of `(roundedAmount -25.0)`.

As such, it's like having a line of code stating `42;`

Comment: I tried that. I've tried
`roundedAmount = roundedAmount - 25.0;`
and
`roundedAmount -= 25.0`
but I always get the same error.

EDIT: I'm not sure what was going on, but the reason I was stumped is because I did try -= like I said, but nothing happened. I restarted my computer for something unrelated and now this is working.

Comment: @RileyMatchett I doubt you'd get the same error if you changed it everywhere consistently. You have multiple non-compilable statements in there.